# How to animate only a percentage of the full CALayer animation along a UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, caanimation, cakeyframeanimation

I manage to animate an CALayer along a UIBezierPath.

What i'm trying to accomplish is to animate only a percentage of the path, for example, only 25% of the path, with the layer staying at that position (at 25%).

What is the way to do this? Here is my code, it always animate the full path.

```
let aPath = UIBizierPath(CGPath: somePath)
let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
anim.path = aPath.CGPath
anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
anim.repeatCount = 1
anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
anim.removedOnCompletion = false
anim.duration = 3.0
anim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

ticker.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "animate_ticker")
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple change one property:

```
anim.repeatCount = 0.25
```

Here is an  [excellent article on animation timing](http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/),you can  learn how to have even more fine-grained control over your animations.

Append:
1. To achieve what you want ,the closest way is to have an 25% subPath ,here is some  [helper method](https://github.com/adamwulf/PerformanceBezier/blob/master/PerformanceBezier/UIBezierPath%2BUtil.h).

2.If you can stand the speed difference,Use the method above, and set back the position when animation ends:

```
ticker.position = ticker.presentationLayer().position
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the animation won't stop 1/4 of the way through the *path*, only 1/4 of the way through the *animation*. Therefore with a `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut` timing function and 0.25 for the `repeatCount`, the animation will stop sooner than expected. Furthermore, the timing function will still be applied to the entire animation's duration – and therefore it'll appear to speed up and then suddenly stop, which may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: @originaluser2, you are correct. I found the animation stopping not perfectly where I thought it would, so this explains it! Thanks! I am looking for 1/4 of the path, not the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Not only `CGPath` is opaque, but also `CAAnimation` doesn't support any updates or notifications for ongoing animations (i.e. after started but before finished). The only entities involved are animation itself and `CALayer`-s it is applied to.

So, options are:

(some options may sound too scary but they are not, so I made an example project, see below)

## repeatCount

As wj2061 mentioned is [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940322/how-to-animate-only-a-percentage-of-the-full-calayer-animation-along-a-uibezierp) you can tweak animation's `repeatCount`. Cons is it will animate 0.25 of animation time, not 0.25 of path

## CAShapeLayer

If, by any chance, you can represent your `ticker` with `CAShapeLayer` segment then you can animate `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` so it will look like segment is moving along the path

## Clever repeatCount

You can calculate such `repeatCount` value that animation will stop at 0.25 of path.

- grab some bezier lib
- extract bezier from timing function with `getControlPointAtIndex:`
- solve bezier to get its "progress value" (usually named `t`) for which bezier's 'y' value will match to your "required progress" (0.25)
- calculate bezier's 'x' value for that `t` - this is exact value of `repeatCount` you need

## Animating with CAAnimation, all by yourself

kind of advanced

- grab some bezier lib
- create custom CALayer subclass with dynamic property, let's say `rideProgress`
- add synthesized properties for bezier path (from bezier lib, not CGPath) and sublayer (say, `rideLayer`) to animate
- override `needsDisplayForKey:` for `rideProgress` key and `initWithLayer:` for all introduced properties BUT use `self.rideLayer?.presentationLayer()` instead of copying `rideLayer`
- override one of these: `drawInContext:` and draw what you need in it; or (better) `display`, in `display` retrieve current `rideProgress` value from `presentationLayer` and update sublayer, then call super. Either way, use bezier lib to calculate position and rotation for sublayer accordingly to current `rideProgress` value
- don't forget to `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)` before setting any animatable property of any layer
- finally, use any kind of CAAnimation or implicit animation on `rideProgress` property

## Split path

Again, suggested by [wj2061](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940322/how-to-animate-only-a-percentage-of-the-full-calayer-animation-along-a-uibezierp). You can split the path so one of halves will represent 0.25 of original

---

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2wJh6Wz7BI8c21Kb1d4ZVN5Vjg) is example implementation of everything above EXCEPT "Split path". I didn't run any field tests on this code, it's just a working concept. XCode 7.3.1, Swift.

---

Materials used: [Wiki on Cubic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function), [Great article about operations on beziers](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives), [Cubic equations solving method line-by-line](http://www.1728.org/cubic2.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set **fromValue** and **toValue** properties? It should work if you set **fromValue** to **0.0** and **toValue** to **0.25**

Comment: `fromValue` and `toValue` are introduced in `CABasicAnimation` which is not a superclass to `CAKeyframeAnimation`

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, and I wanted to animate the drawing of a Path but only a percentage of it.

What I ended up doing was setting the layer's strokeStart and strokeEnd to same floating point values as the animation.

So in your example, try setting `anim.fromValue = 0.0f`, anim.toValue = 0.6f and also `ticker.strokeStart=0.0f` and `ticker.strokeEnd = 0.6f`.

This successfully drew only 60% of the path and animated it too!

Comment: I don't remember the exact reasons, but this didn't work. (I'm not the one who downvoted)